# Loading windows keystore leaves background process running

Tags: java, keystore

Loading a windows keystore(`Windows-MY`) which contains a token based key is leaving the java process as a background process.

I had registered a shutdown hook, the hook is getting executed and Visual VM is reporting the application is terminated, <strike>but the ports opened by the process is not released(like jmx port) unless the process is terminated explicitly using task manager</strike>.

A very simple test case used is as below, but to test the case you have to plugin a key token.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    keyStore.load(null, null);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Close");
        }
    });
    //System.exit(1); even with explicit call to exit nothing is happening
}
```

Edit: Looks like giving the example of ports have done more harm than good. I gave the example of the jmx port as just an example for the fact that the original process was not terminated. If the processes is terminated then the ports are released.

Comment: Can you connect to the process via `jconsole`? If so: Are there any non-daemon threads?

Comment: @AaronDigulla once the program is exited jconsole no longer responds... the same is happening with VisualVM

Comment: @AaronDigulla after a while the following error is thrown `WARNING: Failed to check the connection: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` - but the process is still present in the task manager

Comment: Try `Socket.close();` and if threads are still appearing try `System.exit(0);`

Comment: @l'L'l there are no sockets opened explicitly... so I think there is no way to close any... also `System.exit(0)` is already tried

Comment: Which ports does the process open? Does it try to connect to a remote server? Is your anti-virus running and using the latest patterns?

Comment: @AaronDigulla the ports are opened for jmx... that is not the main problem... problem is the background process.. even if I remove jmx the process is not getting terminated...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So the question is: Why would the JMX service hang? Normally, the JMX service waits for a connection. It shouldn't block the VM (and apparently, it doesn't since the VM exits but the Java process stays alive). I'd suspect an odd firewall setting if you couldn't connect to the process via VisualVM or `jconsole`. Odd.

Comment: One more thought, what `read timeout` values are you using? Increasing it might work.

Comment: @AaronDigulla are you aware of any resource that the keystore might hold in case of the windows store? is there any methods like close that can be used to release any such resources.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: The Keystore itself shouldn't open any ports. Java will open ports when do things like `java -classpath http://...` (i.e. load JARs via HTTP URLs) or when someone makes a JMX connection. But if the code above is the whole application, then it shouldn't open any ports and even when it does, it shouldn't block. Maybe you have an agent on the command line (`-javaagent` option)?

Comment: @AaronDigulla there are no agents.... I'm running the main method from eclipse IDE directly... also from command line

Comment: If I comment `keyStore.load(null, null);` the issue won't come... so it is related to how java is handling `MSCAPI`